# Generic function with traits to read a number complaining about Error trait

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to make a generic function to read a number from stdin:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn read_number<F: FromStr>(prompt: &str) -> Result<F, Box<Error>> {
    let mut guess = String::new();
    let mut sout = io::stdout();

    sout.write(prompt.as_bytes())?;

    sout.flush()?;

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)?;

    Ok(guess.trim().parse()?)
}

fn read_until_number<F: FromStr>(prompt: &str) -> F {
    loop {
        match read_number(prompt) {
            Ok(num) => break num,
            Err(_) => println!("Please enter valid number."),
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: u32 = read_until_number("Enter integer:\n");
    let y: f32 = read_until_number("Enter float:\n");
    println!("You entered this integer: {} and this float: {}", x, y);
}
```

It's not working; I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `<F as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:8
   |
16 |     Ok(guess.trim().parse()?)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `<F as std::str::FromStr>::Err`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where <F as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::error::Error` bound
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::convert::From<<F as std::str::FromStr>::Err>` for `std::boxed::Box<std::error::Error>`
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you what to do:

```
consider adding a `where <F as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::error::Error` bound
```

Following the suggestion, but using a simpler syntax:

```
fn read_number<F>(prompt: &str) -> Result<F, Box<Error>>
where
    F: FromStr,
    F::Err: std::error::Error,
```

This leads to another error which also tells you what to do:

```
error[E0310]: the associated type `<F as std::str::FromStr>::Err` may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:20:8
   |
20 |     Ok(guess.trim().parse()?)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `<F as std::str::FromStr>::Err: 'static`...
note: ...so that the type `<F as std::str::FromStr>::Err` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:20:8
   |
20 |     Ok(guess.trim().parse()?)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Following the suggestion and adding it to our existing restriction:

```
fn read_number<F>(prompt: &str) -> Result<F, Box<Error>>
where
    F: FromStr,
    F::Err: std::error::Error + 'static,
```

You'll then get the same errors for the `read_until_number` function. Repeating the same process, you end up with:

```
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use std::io::Write;
use std::str::FromStr;

fn read_number<F>(prompt: &str) -> Result<F, Box<Error>>
where
    F: FromStr,
    F::Err: std::error::Error + 'static,
{
    let mut guess = String::new();
    let mut sout = io::stdout();

    sout.write(prompt.as_bytes())?;

    sout.flush()?;

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut guess)?;

    Ok(guess.trim().parse()?)
}

fn read_until_number<F>(prompt: &str) -> F
where
    F: FromStr,
    F::Err: std::error::Error + 'static,
{
    loop {
        match read_number(prompt) {
            Ok(num) => break num,
            Err(_) => println!("Please enter valid number."),
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x: u32 = read_until_number("Enter integer:\n");
    let y: f32 = read_until_number("Enter float:\n");
    println!("You entered this integer: {} and this float: {}", x, y);
}
```

---

Why is this needed?

1. The [implementation of `From` for `Box<Error>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-From%3CE%3E) requires that the type implement [`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), but the trait [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) does not have that restriction on the associated `Err` type. You have to add the restriction to your function to be able to perform the conversion.
2. By default, a trait object in argument position has an implicit `'static` bound, the same as if you had done `Box<Error + 'static>`. You *could* change `read_number` to use more nuanced lifetimes, but you couldn't change `read_until_number` since the error has to live outside of the function:

   ```
   fn read_number<'a, F>(prompt: &'a str) -> Result<F, Box<Error + 'a>>
   where
       F: FromStr,
       F::Err: std::error::Error + 'a,
   ```